# Change first period to a comma on multiple lines in Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I am just finding my way around Sublime Text 3, so please be patient is this obvious to all you power users out there.

I want to change the first period `.` in multiple lines, and replace it with a comma `,` instead.

How to do that?

Example of my text:

```
something.here, more.words.here
somethingdifferent.ishere, and.morewords.again
```

I just want to change the first period in each line, not all periods, so that it will read:

```
Something,here, more.words.here
Somethingdifferent,ishere, and.morewords.again
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be more sophisticated ways to do this, but one way is to turn on regular expression searching and do a search for:

```
^([^.]*)\.
```

and replace with

```
\1,
```

and then replace all. Just run it once across the entire file.

That search looks for the beginning of a line (^) and then 0 or more characters that are not periods, followed by a period. It replaces it with that first set of characters, followed by a comma. (The backslash before the period at the end of the search is essential, as the period is a special character that can take the place of any character without that escape.)

Comment: Great! That works, and your explanation was really useful as well. Thanks. (Will accept as soon as I can)